# How do I show the language (keyboard layout) indicator in the panel?

Tags: gnome, input-language

Gnome-Shell how to show in panel language indicator (keyboard layout)
How to enable it in panel?

Answer (score 2):

if you go to the Activities panel and type in keyboard the first thing that pops up should be keyboard input which should add an item to your panel where you can modify this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Activities" Panel, Type "Region" and the icon for "Region & Language" will appear. Click on it, or just press enter if selected. On the new window, click on the tab "Distributions" and add a new keyboard distribution.

Sorry if the instructions are not accurate, but my desktop is in spanish.

Comment: well, I've already added keyborad layout. But I can't see indicator of current layout in top panel

Comment: Obsolete content: today (2023) here you can only choose the language used by the desktop apps, and nothing about the keyboard layout.